# Pass data from ajax function to mvc4 method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a simple MVC4 application with C# and jQuery. In this application, when the user presses a button with the id of `SaveCheckboxChanges` I want to send two arrays of data to the server, via ajax, using jQuery.

These arrays of data are then read by the server and processed accordingly.

The controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCheckBoxes(string requiresSetupArray, string disabledArray){
    return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The Javascript jQuery code:

```
$("#SaveCheckboxChanges").click(function (event) {
            if (!$("#SaveCheckboxChanges").hasClass("disabled")) {
                var requiresSetupArray = [0, 1, 2];
                var disabledArray = [4, 5, 6];

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Material/UpdateCheckBoxes',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({requiresSetupArray: requiresSetupArray, disabledArray: disabledArray }),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("Success ")
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

The problem so far is that even though the method in the controller is being called correctly, the parameters are always null! 
What am I missing? Why is my Ajax method not deliverying the information?

Comment: Your parameters are `string`. They should be `string[]` (or `int[]`)

Comment: Why do you stringify your json-object? Send it as JSON-object instead, should do the trick.

Comment: I have to stringify it otherwise I get an undefined type :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing your controller method parameters and then set the AJAX traditional parameter to true:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateCheckBoxes(int[] requiresSetupArray, int[] disabledArray){
    return Json("chamara", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#SaveCheckboxChanges").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     if (!$("#SaveCheckboxChanges").hasClass("disabled")) {
         var requiresSetupArray = [0, 1, 2];
         var disabledArray = [4, 5, 6];

         $.ajax({
             url: '/Material/UpdateCheckBoxes',
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             traditional: true,
             data: JSON.stringify({
                requiresSetupArray: requiresSetupArray, 
                disabledArray: disabledArray 
             }),
             success: function (data) {
                alert("Success " + checkBoxesNumber)
             },
             error: function () {
                alert("error");
             }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution does not work. Unfortunatly, you forgot to stringify the objects. Other than that, its all good. Please update your answer so I can accept it :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having two strings as parameters in the Controller you could have an C# object containing two two arrays as the in parameter in the method. The object will automatically be populated by the values of the posted data. Something like:

```
public class Something
{
    public List<int> RequiresSetupArray {get;set;}
    public List<int> DisabledArray {get;set;}
}
```